# data is undefined although using async and await

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, axios

I am sorry, but although i searched for the solution i can not fix the problem.

I can get the res, but can not access it with res.data.

I have tried to fix it by using an asynchronous arrow function.

```
class QuizLoader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = { 
    receivedData: []
   }
  }

  //load data
  componentDidMount() {
   this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () => {
   const dataBefore =  this.state.receivedData;
   console.log("receivedData before sending is ");
   console.log(dataBefore);


   // get Quiz data from database
   let res = await axios
   .get('https://backend-pflegonaut.firebaseio.com/.json')
   .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
   });

   let { data } = res.data;
```

*Here i only get undefined*

```
   console.log({res});
```

*see code below*

```
   this.setState({receivedData: data});
  }

render() { 
 return ( 
    <div>
      {this.state.receivedData.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
```

*second problem here: this.state.receivedData.map is not a function*

```
        this.state.receivedData.map((e, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{e.Frage}</div>;
        }
```

*Also tried: this.state.receivedData.Object.map*

```
       )
      )}
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default QuizLoader;
```

**data overview in the console.log:**

[image: console]

Comment: console: {res: {…}}
res:
config: {url: "https://backend-pflegonaut.firebaseio.com/.json", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: {Frage2: {…}, Frage3: {…}, Quiz: {…}}
headers: {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", cache-control: "no-cache", content-length: "439"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: so the data is in there :)

Comment: Hi Pflegonaut, try my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Comment: hey thanks for the fast help :) I put in the try catch statement but unfortunately ´console.log({data})´ is still undefined.

Comment: You're not destructuring the object correctly :). You're going one level too deep. It should just be `let { data } = res`  @Pflegonaut

Comment: thanks @ChristopherNgo!!! it worked :) i just love stackoverflow :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is the freaking best :)! I've learned so much from this site. Honestly the user-base is so friendly and filled with great teachers. Let me know if you have any other questions. My answer below should explain in-depth what is happening. Please consider upvoting and marking it as the solution :)

Comment: i did not post enough to upvote it :) honestly i have another problem, which is linked to the solved one. I feel free to post it under the solution section.

Comment: Yeah feel free to :). I can take a swing at it. But also feel free to open up another question as well. There's nothing wrong with having more questions.

Comment: i edited the question :) going to delete this after solution, not to spam the world

Comment: Its because your response.data doesn't appear to return an array, but an object instead. That's strange. When you do `console.log(this.state.receivedData)`, is there any particular item in that object that you want to use, that is supposed to be an array?

Comment: Yes. I would like to use the nested objects `Antwort1-4` as an array to shuffle it later randomly.

Comment: Hmm it looks like you can choose from Frage2, Frage3 or Quiz.  Which one include Antwort1-4?

Comment: I am sorry I explained my question so badly!
It was: Antwort1, Antwort2, Anwort3, Antwort4. All of them should be shuffled randomly in one array for a quiz (Antwort = answer in german).

Comment: Oh no worries! I understand what you mean. The problem is that there are multiple Frage (Questions) in the response object. So It's unclear which of the key-value pairs you would want to use for the `.map()` I'm assuming you actually want to use `this.state.responseData.Quiz`

Comment: Ah I see. How would you structure the firebase database then?

Comment: We probably don't have to restructure the Firebase database. We can just work with what we have. :). i've updated my solution below to render the questions. If that doesn't work, then maybe you should consider restructuring it so it returns an array of objects instead :)

Comment: works like charm. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `axios` request seems a bit malformed. Also when you destructure `res.data` by doing:

`let { data } = res.data`

The code is trying to make a new `data` variable by using a `key-value pair` inside `res.data` (which it doesn't have because this is actually the array you want). You're going one level too deep. It should just be:

`let { data } = res`.

Try this, it's the current convention of working with `async/await`:

```
  getData = async () => {
     const dataBefore =  this.state.receivedData;
     try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://backend-pflegonaut.firebaseio.com/.json")

        let { data } = res //turns the data key-value pair into a variable

        this.setState( {receivedData: data} );

     } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
     }
   }
```

As for you quiz-rendering. It looks like you want to display a list of questions with their corresponding answer-set. Try something like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.receivedData.length === 0 ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          Object.entries(this.state.receivedData)
            .filter(([key, obj]) => key.includes("Frage"))
            .map(([question, obj]) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h4>{question}</h4>
                  {Object.values(obj).map((answer, i) => {
                    return <div key={i}>{answer}</div>;
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```